# Using xbee ansic library for usb interface

Tags: raspberry-pi, xbee, zigbee

I have a raspberry pi board conencted to xbee device via usb adapter. ie: To access my xbee, it will be /dev/ttyUSB. I want to use xbee ansic library api's to send and receive commands from/to my xbee device.
Have downloaded xbee ansic library code from https://github.com/digidotcom/xbee_ansic_library.git

1. How to build xbee ansic library and build some .so  (Makefiles are only for generating sample files executables)
2. Can I use it for usb interface (all examples are for serial interface)
3. How can I query temperature from xbee device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It was designed for building complete, stand-alone programs.  It targets embedded systems without an OS, where you compile a single program to run on the processor.  I guess it's possible to modify it to build a library, but in many instances you have compile-time configuration going on.
2. Your USB interface is essentially serial once it gets to the XBee module.  Just specify the correct /dev/tty device.
3. You'll have to look up the documentation of the device.  Some modules report on their internal temperature (which is likely higher than ambient) using remote AT commands.

Comment: Thanks Tom for the answer